# JS setting attr(value) don't returning in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, websocket

I'm using WebSocketd to send data and retrieve it form STDOUT, then using JS to access the message:

```
   var ws = new WebSocket('ws://ip-address:8081/');
   ws.onopen = function() {
        document.getElementById("phone").style.background= '#cfc';
      };
   ws.onclose = function() {
        document.getElementById("phone").style.background= '#fcc';
   };
   ws.onmessage = function(event) {
          $('#phone').attr('value',  event.data);
   };
```

It work perfectly, then I tried the following to test if the value of #phone will be change after setting the websocket connction

```
var max = 10;
$('#phone').focus(function(e)
{  
  if ($(this).val().length > max) 
  { alert('action fired') 
  }
})
.keyup(function(e){  
  if ($(this).val().length > max) { 
      alert('action fired') 
  }
});
```

but this don't work until i input a text manually

Comment: Side note, `$('#phone').val(event.data)` is the setter version of `val()`

Comment: I used both, same result

Comment: Also just to make sure.  When you say "it works perfectly" means you see the value in the input box before you focus?

Comment: Well, by definition if you're assigning the value of an input programmatically, a `keyup` event won't fire, nor a focus. You can manually send a focus/keyup event which should work.

Comment: yes, I see the value in the input box before focus

Comment: That's strange then.  Given your logic, if the keyup is happening, that mean's you are bound to the element, so I would assume the focus would work if the conditional is true.  Have you tried console logging the input value in the focus method to see what it thinks the value is?

Comment: @Hisham What do you expect to see after the WebSocket connection is established?

Comment: @hev1 I already can see the message sent by Websocketd in the input text, lets say it is 123456, on focus: a JS will run and I retrieve a data from  mongodb, it work fine if I enter the number manually, but when the value is setting by JS nothing happen

Comment: @Hisham Have you read my answer?

Comment: @hev1 yes, It works too.. thank you

Comment: @Hisham No problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, setting the value of an input programmatically will not `focus` it, nor will it trigger a `keyup` event to trigger. You can, however, trigger the `focus` event or `keyup` event manually after the WebSocket sends a message. This may be what you're looking for;

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://ip-address:8081/');
ws.onopen = function() {
     document.getElementById("phone").style.background= '#cfc';
};
ws.onclose = function() {
     document.getElementById("phone").style.background= '#fcc';
};
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
       $('#phone').val(event.data);
       $("#phone").focus(); //we now focus the input which should fire your focus event listener
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the value of the `input` using Javascript, the `keyup` and `focus` events naturally won't fire. You will need to use Javascript to `focus` on the `input`.

Change

```
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
      $('#phone').attr('value',  event.data);
};
```

To

```
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
      $('#phone').attr('value',  event.data);
      $('#phone').focus();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone"/>
<p/>
<textarea id="message">
</textarea>
<br/>
<button id="sendMessage">Send</button>
<script>
var max = 10;
$('#sendMessage').click(function(e){
   //simulating a sent message
    $('#phone').attr('value', $('#message').val());
    $('#phone').focus();
});
$('#message').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13){
  //simulating a sent message
    $('#phone').attr('value', $('#message').val());
    $('#phone').focus();
  }
});
$('#phone').focus(function(e)
{  
  if ($(this).val().length > max) 
  { console.log('action fired') 
  }
})
.keyup(function(e){  
  if ($(this).val().length > max) { 
      console.log('action fired') 
  }
});
</script>
```